# How to aggregate a data set of geocodes to reduce there numbers for a heat map?

Tags: algorithm, go, heatmap

I have a data set of Latitudes and Longitudes for populating a heat map. The data is too large and will keep on increasing day by day. I need to reduce the amount of data without much affecting the performance of the heat map. I understand we could add one more field for "weight" and combine two near-by points to form a new point with the "weight" as sum of the first two. But I am confused about where to plant the new point. I don't think this will be a standard way for solving my problem. I am using golang for the implementation, but all ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: use the weights for a weighted average, and put move the point slightly. e.g. if point A has 0.9 and point B 0.1, the new point should around 0.1 of the line connecting A and B, near A.

Comment: Two important questions: 1. What should the heatmap represent, i.e. what is the definition of the perfect, non-lossy result? Once you define that, question 2. is: what kind of deviations from 1. can you accept?

Comment: @RafałDowgird The heatmap represents the movement of a vehicle.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer is it possible for you to provide an example?

Comment: So, you need to represent the roads/paths/shortcuts from a huge number of car coordinate snapshots, is that more or less correct?

Comment: @RafałDowgird I need to build a Heat Map of the places the car visit with the geo codes. So shortcuts and roads are not important. Just want to get rough idea on which parts of the city this car travelled. By aggregating geocodes with in short distance ,lets say 100m, we could know which ever parts of the city car visited most.

Comment: I've done that by dividing the map in sections (large squares), when new route is added, calculate which blocks it goes through and add 1 to each block. Algorithm for finding squares can be very heavy if done sloppy though.

Comment: what data base you are using? Postgres and Mongo have geo-indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/ and http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html. Also you might be clustering data

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by a commenter, consider using a weighted average of points, for example.

Pick some proximity threshold within which any points will be aggregated. For each of these points, generate a synthetic point whose coordinates are the average (median) of the others and whose weight is the count of the points in question. Include only the synthetic weighted points when generating your heatmap so that you can reduce the amount of data by adjusting your proximity threshold.

For example:

```
type Point struct{ X, Y float32 }

type WeightedPoint struct{ Weight, X, Y float32 }

func GetWeightedPoint(ps []Point) WeightedPoint {
    n := float32(len(ps))
    wp := WeightedPoint{Weight: n}
    if n > 0 {
        for _, p := range ps {
            wp.X += p.X
            wp.Y += p.Y
        }
        wp.X /= n
        wp.Y /= n
    }
    return wp
}

func main() {
    ps := []Point{{0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0}, {0.5, 1.0}}
    fmt.Printf("OK: %#v\n", GetWeightedPoint(ps))
    // OK: main.WeightedPoint{Weight:3, X:0.5, Y:0.33333334}
}
```